# Piecewise feed of a function with values from two vectors

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

i've got a special question about my item-based collaborative filtering algorithm written by myself. The algorithm is based on equation (4) of [this  article](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1100000/1099689/p485-ding.pdf?ip=192.44.85.25&id=1099689&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=2BA2C432AB83DA15.EFC97FAB8374CA2B.4D4702B0C3E38B35.4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=578955792&CFTOKEN=75541764&__acm__=1454088805_add73c4cbc58ec0ed11f3c038fc24678) by Yi Ding and Xue Li.

The Algorithm is modified by the following exceptions. If the similarity of I(c) and I(j) is smaller than 0 the similarity will be multiplicated  by -1 and therefore the rating 0(ic) will be flipped to 6-0(ic).
For example if the similarity is -0.5 and the rating is 5 the equation will produce the value ((-0.5)*-1)*(6-5)=0.5. I wrote the following code in R:

```
func_pred2 <- function(i,j)
{
  a1 <- UI_ratings_sim[,j]
  b1 <- sort(a1,decreasing=TRUE)
  c1 <- b1[-1]
  c2 <- ifelse(c1<0,c1*-1,c1*1)
  c3 <- names(c2)
  c4 <- UI_ratings[i,c3]
  c5 <- ifelse(c1<0,6-c4,c4*1)
  d1 <- UI_time_dist_efunc[i,c3]

  e1 <- as.vector(c5)
  e2 <- as.vector(c2)
  e3 <- as.vector(d1)

  count <- sum(e1*e2*e3,na.rm=TRUE)

  denom <- sum(e2*e3,na.rm=TRUE)

  pred <- count/denom

  return(pred)
}
```

Some further explanations:

UI_ratings_sim is a matrix consisting of correlations of the Items to each other and UI_ratings is a two dimensional matrix with Users and Items and the ratings for the Items. I have generated a matrix which is consisting of positions in the matrix for which ratings should be predicted. My question is if i'm able to put the values of the vectors picewise for i and j in the function. If i am training to put the whole two vectors in the function the one vector for i and the other for j i get 0 as the result. I would be very glad if anybody would help me.

Comment: your question is that you want to pass two entire vectors? look at `?Vectorize` and use as `Vectorize(func_pred2)`

Comment: Thank you very much, that you are willing to help me ;) i want to solve this problem: assumed i have got to vectors i and j with i=c(1,2,3,4,5) and j=c(6,7,8,9,10). My aim is to put values in func_pred2 this way:

Comment: Thank you very much, that you are willing to help me ;) i want to solve this problem: assumed i have got to vectors i and j with i=c(1,2,3,4,5) and j=c(6,7,8,9,10). My aim is to put values in func_pred2 this way: first prediction: func_pred2(1,6), second prediction: func_pred2(2,7), third prediction: func_pred2(3,8) and so on. So that i'm able to put the 2 vectors picewise in my function, i hope you are understanding my aim :D

Comment: try `outer(i, j, Vectorize(func_pred2))` cant test since you have undefined variables